# ReactJS 16.13.1 Hook incoherent state in listener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I don't understand which magic operate here, I try everything is come up in my mind, I can't fix that problem.

I want to use an array which is in the react state of my component in a websocket listener, when the listener is triggered my state is an empty array, however I set a value in an useEffect.

Here my code :

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);
    const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        someAxiosCallWrapped((response) => {
            const infos = response.data;
            setMyData(infos.data);
            const socket = getSocket(info.socketNamespace); // wrap in socket namespace
            handleEvents(socket);
        });
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        setSortedData(sortTheArray(myData));
    }, [myData]);

    const handleEvents = (socket) => {
        socket.on('EVENT_NAME', handleThisEvent);
    };

    const handleThisEvent = payload => {
        const myDataCloned = [...myData]; //<=== my probleme is here, whatever I've tried myData is always an empty array, I don't understand why
        /**
         * onHandleEvent is an external function, just push one new object in the array no problem in the function
         */
        onHandleEvent(myDataCloned, payload);
        setMyData(myDataCloned);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            // display sortedData no problem here
        </div>
    );
}
```

Probably missed something obvious, if someone see what.

Thanks !

Comment: why are you setting data again in `handeThisEvent`?

Comment: Because it's the point of my event handler adding some data in the component from a websocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function):

> Any function inside a component, including event handlers and effects, “sees” the props and state from the render it was created in.

Here `handleEvents` is called from `useEffect` on mount and hence it sees only the initial data ([]). To catch this error better, we can move the functions inside `useEffect` (unless absolutely necessary outside)

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleEvents = (socket) => {
    socket.on('EVENT_NAME', handleThisEvent);
  };

  const handleThisEvent = payload => {
      const myDataCloned = [...myData];
      onHandleEvent(myDataCloned, payload);
  };

  someAxiosCallWrapped((response) => {
    const infos = response.data;
    setMyData(infos.data);
    const socket = getSocket(info.socketNamespace); // wrap in socket namespace
    handleEvents(socket);
  });

  return () => {
    socket.off('EVENT_NAME', handleThisEvent);
  }
}, [myData, onHandleEvent]);
```

Now, you can see that the `useEffect` has dependencies on `myData` and `onHandleEvent`. We did not introduce this dependency now, it already had these, we are just seeing them more clearly now.

Also note that we are removing the listener on change of `useEffect`. If `onHandleEvent` changes on every render, you would to wrap that with `useCallback` in parent component.

[Is it safe to omit a function from dependencies - Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses, that was exactly the problem.

I put everything in the first useEffect, because I considered this part as initialization of my component, I felt the part of why I keep going having the initials values outside the useEffect without really understanding the why.

Comment: FTR: eslint rule [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) is useful to identify missing dependencies

Answer (score 0):

you need to use useMemo hook to update the function once the array value changed unless Hooks Component will always use initial state value.
change the problem part to this and try

```
const handleThisEvent = useMemo(payload => {
       const myDataCloned = [...myData]; 
       onHandleEvent(myDataCloned, payload);
       setMyData(myDataCloned);
   },[the values you need to look for(In this case myData)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finaly come up with a code like that.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let socket;
  someAxiosCallWrapped((response) => {
    const infos = response.data;
    setMyData(infos.data);
    socket = getSocket(info.socketNamespace); // wrap in socket namespace
    setSocket(socket)

  });

  return () => {
    if(socket) {
        socket.disconnect();
    }
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if(socket) {
        const handleEvents = (socket) => {
        socket.off('EVENT_NAME').on('EVENT_NAME', handleThisEvent);
      };

      const handleThisEvent = payload => {
          const myDataCloned = [...myData];
          onHandleEvent(myDataCloned, payload);
      };
    }
}, [socket, myData, onHandleEvent]);
```

Thanks to Agney !